# Equivalence Relation between Derivative Being Odd and Function Being Even

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, self-learning

In the exercise, I am required to prove that

$f'$ is odd $\iff$ $f$ is even

Moving from right to left was pretty trivial, however, I couldn't move from left to right. Note that we can only use very basic things like the definition of the derivative and rules of differentiation (No mean value theorem or any other theorems.)

I cannot even see the left implying the right, but I hope I will see it after you guys explain how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: No, I can't. There's no integration yet (although I already know it)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use contraposition. Suppose $f(-x)\ne f(x)$, then $-f'(-x)\ne f'(x)$.

Here I used the fact that $f'=g'$ implies that $f$ and $g$ differ only by a constant. If $f(x)-g(x)=h(x)$, then $f'(x)-g'(x)=h'(x)$. This implies $h'(x)=0$. $h(x)$ is then a constant. You might use k_g's suggestion to prove this basic theorem to proceed.

So we also need to note the special case where $f$ and $g$ only differ by a constant, let $f(-x)=f(x)+C$, in this case $-f'(-x)=f'(x)$. But it also implies $f(0)=f(0)+C$, i.e., $C=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer. Just for the sake of it, isn't this contraposition? You just proved that $not\ q\implies\ not\ p$, or am I wrong here too?

Comment: And *how* to prove $f(−x)\ne f(x)\implies -f′(−x)\ne f′(x)$ ? Is false in general, as your "special case" proves.

Comment: @HasanSaad: You are right. It is contraposition.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: I believe it is not false. But that was actually a corollary of mean value theorem, which says only when $f$ and $g$ differ by a constant, $f'=g'$. And that's why the special case.

Comment: OK. Better edit the answer. The mean value theorem is the essential ingredient.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Edited. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: We're not allowed to use the mean-value theorem though...

Comment: @HasanSaad: Yes. But I am thinking there should be a way to bypass that.

Comment: I really hope you can find that. This problem frustrated me...

Answer (score 8):

Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$. If $f'(-x)=-f'(x)$, then
$$
\begin{align}
g'(x)
&=f'(x)+f'(-x)\tag{1}\\
&=f'(x)-f'(x)\tag{2}\\
&=0\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: chain rule and the definition of $g$
$(2)$: $f'$ is odd
$(3)$: $a-a=0$

Thus, $g(x)$ is constant. Since $g(0)=f(0)-f(0)=0$, $g(x)=0$ for all $x$. Thus,
$$
f(x)=f(-x)
$$
Therefore, $f$ is even.

Comment: Using integration is not allowed as this comes in the chapter previous to the integration one, else it would be easy.

Comment: @HasanSaad: I hope we can use that if $g'(x)=0$ for all $x$, then $g$ is constant. It is hard to know what we can use.

Comment: We're not even supposed to use that... Should I give up?

Comment: @HasanSaad You should prove one of those theorems from first principles. Then you should be able to use it :-)

Comment: No integration is needed in any part of the process. Chain rule does not involve integration, and coming back from g'(x) = 0 to g being constant neither does.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f$ even $\iff$ $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$. Then
$$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(-x)=\cdots$$
(apply chain rule)

Comment: Maybe it's just a fault in my logic (that I hope to fix), but I can only see you moving from right to left in the last step. I cannot see the equivalence here. It seems to me that you used the fact that $f$ is even to prove that $f'$ is odd but I cannot see the converse... Sorry.

Comment: @HasanSaad, I was thinking in the fundamental theorem of calculus (comment of user24142 1 min after my answer)...

Comment: It would have been easy if I could use that (I originally thought of it) but since he did not put integration yet, I suppose I had to solve it using some other basic method.